# how to prevent forgery when updating data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am trying to to update my existing data from data list, that is-

```
Students List

Student ID   Name            Email              Actions
std-000001  Imdad       imdad@example.com       Update Delete
std-000002  Ahsan       ahsan@example.net       Update Delete
std-000003  Imdad       imdadul@yahoo.com       Update Delete
std-000004  Mortuza     mortuza@test.net        Update Delete
std-000005  Hossain     hossain@hotmail.com     Update Delete
std-000007  sajeda      sajeda@gmail.com        Update Delete
std-000008  Hossain     hossain@example.com     Update Delete
std-000009  Akter        akter@test.org         Update Delete
```

my table for listing data is -

```
<table style="width:100vw" border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Student ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$item->email}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{url('update-student/' . $item->id)}}">Update</a>
                <a href="{{url('delete-student/' . $item->id)}}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

my url is when I click on edit link: http://localhost:8000/update-student/std-000001

My form for updating student is-

```
<form action="{{url('store-student/')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="student-id" placeholder="Enter Student ID" value="{{$data->id ? $data->id : old('id')}}">@error('id') <span>{{$message}}</span>@enderror

    <p>Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type="text" name="name" id="student-name" placeholder="Enter name" value="{{$data->name? $data->name: old('name')}}">@error('name') <span>{{$message}}</span>@enderror</p>

    <p>Email: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type="text" name="email" id="student-email" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{$data->email ? $data->email : old('email')}}">@error('email') <span>{{$message}}</span>@enderror</p>

    <button id="student-form-submit-button" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

my routes are -

```
Route::get('update-student/{id?}', [StudentController::class, 'updateStudent']);
Route::post('store-student', [StudentController::class, 'storeStudent']);
```

and my function to update data is-

```
public function updateStudent($id)
    {
        $student = DB::table('students')->find($id);
        return view('update_student_form', ['data' => $student]);
    }

    public function storeStudent(Request $request)
    {
        $request = $request->all();
        unset($request['_token']);
        echo $success = DB::table('students')->where('id', $request['id'])->update($request);
    }
```

It's possible to manipulate another student data by changing student id query of url and inspecting hidden input value id named input.

Is it possible to prevent from doing so? is there any way ? thank you.

Comment: Authentication and authorisation. Check the ID of the signed in user matches the ID of the record they're trying to interact with

Comment: Thank  you @ADyson. But if one has authorization for all table row updating then what?

Comment: @Solutions If they have permission to change the record, then what's the problem with them changing it? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want that on one can change primary key id either form url or from hidden input field

Comment: `if one has authorization for all table row updating then what`...if they have a role which allows them to update any row, then obviously for those people you wouldn't run the check I described above. So you need to check the user's role first to determine what they can do.